# Insert Arraylist into Derby Database table

Tags: java, sql, arraylist, derby

Hi I am having problems inserting a array list into a derby database below is my insert to table method:

```
   private static void insertPerson(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String Street, String City) {
    try {
        stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("insert into " + tableName + " values (" + id + ",'" + firstName + "','" + lastName + "','" + Street + "','" + City + "')");
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I am trying to `insert into database` with the following code:

```
ArrayList PersonList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(formatedString.split(",")));
    for (int i = 0; i < PersonList.size(); i++) {
    String []value=formatedString.split(",");
   insertPerson(value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4]);
   System.out.println(PersonList.toString());
  }
```

I am getting the following error:

Exception in thread `AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

Any suggestion would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the problem

```
// 1. Split `formatedString` as a List of Persons by `,`
ArrayList PersonList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(formatedString.split(",")));
// 2. Walk through the list of persons
for (int i = 0; i < PersonList.size(); i++) {
    // 3. Split the same `formatedString` in fields ?!?
    // What should happen here?
    // II think this is your problem        
    String []value=formatedString.split(",");
    insertPerson(value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4]);
    System.out.println(PersonList.toString());
}
```

**UPDATE**

A working example with your data (linebreaks between the persons - spaces between the fields)

```
public class Splitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String values = "1 Ola Hansen Timoteivn Sandnes\n"
                + "2 Tove Svendson Borgvn Stavanger\n"
                + "3 Kari Pettersen Storgt Stavanger";
        String[] rows = values.split("\n");
        for (String row : rows) {
            String[] fields = row.split(" ");
            System.out.println(String.format("id: %s firstname: %s lastname: %s street: %s city %s", fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3], fields[4]));
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This example reads the data from a file (`/tmp/test.txt`)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Splitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/tmp/test.txt")));
        String row;
        while ((row = input.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] fields = row.split(" ");
            System.out.println(String.format("id: %s firstname: %s lastname: %s street: %s city %s", fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3], fields[4]));
        }
    }
}
```

The file looks like this

```
1 Ola Hansen Timoteivn Sandnes
2 Tove Svendson Borgvn Stavanger
3 Kari Pettersen Storgt Stavanger
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. i am using this line to String []value=formatedString.split(","); to get the arraylist into values. im not sure of any other way i can get the list into the database .. any suggestions

Comment: Thats ok. But what is inside the `formatedString`? Is it one person with its fields (i.e id, firstname, lastname...) or a list of persons? Can you send an example of the content of the `formatedString`?

Comment: hi its a list of of persons .. this is the formatted string contents 1 Ola Hansen Timoteivn Sandnes
2 Tove Svendson Borgvn Stavanger
3 Kari Pettersen Storgt Stavanger    

the problem is with the code i got i found out that [value] is the problem when i remove the ',' i get the following result the 1OlaHansenTimoteivnSandnes any suggestions ..  thanks

Comment: Is there a linebreak between the persons?

Comment: yes there was..  for testing purposes i removed it but it made no difference

Comment: I have updated my example with a working main class. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for that, but the problem i have is i need to retrieve the data from a txt file and enter that into a database, without physically editing provided text file, i cant edit in code but in notepad for example..

Comment: hi that getting close, 1 lastthing do you know how i can remove 5 items from the array it has created, because the list has column name like id first_name last_name street and city .. thanks alot mate.. you have been really helpfull

Comment: If you know the number of lines you want to skip, you can do it by reading it before the `while` loop by `input.readLine();`. Write it for every line you want to skip. Do not forget to close the `BufferedReader` `input` after your work.

Comment: Thanks for all your time :-) il work on it this evening fingers crossed i get it working

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 means your split (String []value=formatedString.split(",");) isn't working, there isn't anything in value[1] - value [4].  Make sure whatever is in formatedString has 4 commas in it, maybe try System.out.println(formatedString) before you do the split to find what's causing the exception.